# docbook style sheets param.xsl

Tags: xslt, docbook, docbook-xsl

Thank you for the qyuick assistance in finding the Java extension file for Saxon to convert docbook XML into xml.fo. (Question `41362248/docbook-saxon-toolchain-extension-jar-file-cannot-find-same`)

Now, I discovered that I unfortunately
cannot find the correct sytle sheets themselves.  I tried downloading from the docbook sourceforge project page,

```
docbook-xsl-doc-1.79.1.zip
```

from the Files tab, `docbook.xsl`, `1.79.1`, `docbook-xsl-1.79.zip`

The version I did find that did have `docbook.xsl` seems to be missing the `param.xsl`.  Here is the error message I got when I attempted
to convert with **saxon**:

```
Error at xsl:include on line 28 of file:/home/leffstudent/xsl2/xsl/fo/docbook.xsl:
  Failure reading file:/home/leffstudent/xsl2/xsl/fo/param.xsl: /home/leffstudent/xsl2/xsl/fo/param.xsl (No such file or directory)
Transformation failed: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

As I wrote in the above-cited question,
I had all this set up on the Computer Science server at the University where
I teach.   Unfortunately, that server was lost.  I am trying to recreate
the toolchain.
I use docbook to create the class notes for two of my courses.   And
I need this to set up my classes for the Spring 2017 semester.

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this problem. **docbook-xsl-1.79.1.zip** downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/files/docbook-xsl/1.79.1/ does indeed include fo/param.xsl.

Answer (score 0):

mzjn provided the solution I needed.  I downloaded again
 docbook-xsl-1.79.1.zip from sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/files/docbook-xsl/1.79.1

I now created the needed class notes and back at work for the new Spring 2017 semester.
mzjn should make this the official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I did try the instructions in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments, but I was unable to find the indicated things to click to move it to community wiki.

Comment: You can accept your own answers (but you probably have to wait a day or two).